# How to avoid goto and jump when coding in assembly?

Tags: assembly, goto

I'm aware of the numerous posts here and elsewhere on avoiding goto in high-level programming languages. However from the (admittedly small) experience I've had coding in MIPS assembly, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to avoid goto and jump statements in assembly when implementing control flow.

For example how would this code be implemented in assembly (C equivalent):

```
if (x < 2)
  { ans = 0; }
else
  { ans = 1; }
```

Would the use of a goto or jump statement be necessary, or is there a proper way of avoiding them in favor of more appropriate code practices?

Comment: sometimes you can use branchless techniques.  Your example is trivial and would be much better done without a branch: Starting with `x` in edx: `xor eax,eax` / `cmp edx, 2` / `setnl al`.  `ans` is now live in `eax`.

Comment: full sized arm 32 bit instructions have a conditional execution on every instruction so  for your code above you could have a compare, then a mov if less than 0 then a mov if greater than or equal 1 and have no jumps.  other that an instruction set like that gotos are required and happen often, which is why it is baffling that high level languages discourage it. that is how processors work why dont the languages reflect that?

Comment: @old_timer GOTO considered harmful was a reflection on structured programming being hard-to-read spaghetti code. Jumping between memory addresses is very different to Jumping between files and line numbers and pointer declarations for the poor analyst programmer to follow. Higher level abstractions are just that; abstracted away from hardware implementations and towards human understanding. Except for javascript, the exception that proves the rule.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The recommendation to avoid goto in high-level programming languages only applies to - well - high-level languages.

Assembler is a low-level language and jumps are essential.

Answer (score 3):

You can't avoid using jump intruction completely, because you are already almost talking with processor directly.

But with better practice you are applying with high-level programming, you are still able to use less jumps in your assembly code.

Some ideas like:

- Jump inside blocks, not between blocks.
- Jump in a simple and readable logic following traditional for/while/if/case sequence.
- One block of assembly do one thing; minimal side effect.
- Try to use macro or function, don't repeat yourself.

Comment: If you find yourself using more / worse jumps for readability / maintainability reasons, you should probably switch to C and let a compiler do a better job (unless you're writing a tiny bootloader or something that is most naturally written in asm).  But I'd agree with the "jump inside blocks, not between" suggestion, in general.

Answer (score 1):

When you are pressured by everyone to not use goto in high level languages, it is (kind of) understandable to not use goto. But to carry that over to assembly... It is completely impossible to not use jmp while coding in assembly, because there aren't theese hidden goto instructions like for or while.

Answer (score -1):

Although it's not MIPS, for X86 processors, in the case of Microsoft assemblers ML.EXE (16 / 32 bit) and ML64.EXE (64 bit), since MASM 6.11, and all version of Visual Studio, you can use the dot directives:

```
ans     equ     eax

        .if     x < 2
        mov     ans,0
        .else
        mov     ans,1
        .endif
```

In this example, the dot directives translate into compare immediate, jump instructions, and move immediate. For more information, see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t163bt0.aspx

Comment: That's just syntactical sugar on top of branch instructions, but I guess it does prevent asm from turning into spaghetti-code.  Like I commented before, if you're doing a lot of this, instead of thinking hard about how to use fewer branches and make tighter code, you should just use a compiler.

Comment: Really?  What 2 registers would it use to hold a 0 and 1 as inputs to cmov?  Or would it use `setl [ans]`, possibly after storing a zero to the whole `ans` if it's wider.

Comment: Yeah, MASM isn't a compiler.  My understanding was that those `.if` directives just expand to cmp/jcc/jmp in a pretty fixed way.  I think you just broke your example by introducing a `mov mem,mem`, which isn't encodeable.

Comment: Oh, yes I did miss that, oops.  I never use macro names for registers, too easy to accidentally use the same register in conflicting ways unless you rename *all* the registers to a different set of names.  I think the current state of your answer is basically fine as an example of "high level" assembler, unlike actual machine code or normal assembly.  Although `xor eax,eax` / `cmp x, 2` / `setge al` would do the same thing as or more efficiently, and without goto/jump, for this case where the logic is that simple.